# UWP - DataPackage.OperationCompleted is EMPTY & gets called by nobody

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm writing a UWP file manager and I've come to a problem with drag&drop. I'm probably just beating my head against the wall since this is obviously another bug in the platform, but this time I can't find any workaround.

When dragging files and dropping them into File Explorer everything is fine. I fill up the `DataPackage` and listen to the `OperationCompleted` event, which happens when the files finished moving to another folder. When I drop them into another view within my app, I can call `DataPackageView.ReportOperationCompleted`, which does work (sort of). The problem is, it's also called AUTOMATICALLY at the same time the drop happens, even though the operation is not finished yet - and I can't do anything about it. The call stack is completely empty when I hit a breakpoint in the event handler.

On top of that, when I actually look into the arguments of `OperationCompleted`, the `Operation` in `OperationCompletedEventArgs` is ALWAYS None! It's None when File Explorer does the job, it's None when it gets called automatically, it's None when I call it manually, NO MATTER WHAT argument I pass in. Any explanation for this, Microsoft? I'm tired of fixing your bugs, especially when I can't actually do it since the platform is so limited.

Comment: If you just want to Drag and Drop files in UWP. It seems that you don't need to call `DataPackageView.ReportOperationCompleted` event, see [http://jamescroft.co.uk/blog/uwp/implementing-file-drag-drop-in-your-windows-10-uwp-application/](http://jamescroft.co.uk/blog/uwp/implementing-file-drag-drop-in-your-windows-10-uwp-application/)

Comment: No I don't, you're right, that already works but I wanted a notification for when the operation is actually done. And even if I don't actually need it, this is something that definitely should work as other programs could rely on this.

Comment: By the way, one other "curiosity" with drag&dropping files in UWP is that if you get files dropped in your app and a requested operation set to move - you can't actually move them - the files are read-only. Try explaining that to the user.

Answer (score 0):

> one other "curiosity" with drag&dropping files in UWP is that if you get files dropped in your app and a requested operation set to move - you can't actually move them - the files are read-only. Try explaining that to the user.

Not sure how you to move files. In general, you should use `StorageFile.CopyAsync` method. You could use `try/catch` block to wrap this operation like the follwing:

```
try
{
     var operation = appFile.File.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, appFile.File.DisplayName, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("exception msg: "+ex.Message);
}
```

Then if the file is readonly, you will get exception message, you should use this message to notify user.

> I wanted a notification for when the operation is actually done.

You should implemente AsyncOperationWithProgressCompletedHandler for your async operation, then you will get notification when it's completed.

```
operation.Completed = (tresult,tprogress) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("progress msg: "+tprogress); };
```

Comment: Yes, CopyAsync works, but MoveAsync throws an Exception. The files are read-only - I can't access them even though they were dropped into my app by the user. I receive a requested operation of Move - and there's no way to move them.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but that's not what I mean. Of course I know when what I'm doing finished. That's not the point. Any app could drop files into my app, not just my own. You have to report it to the source app - that's the point of the API.